# Как подключиться к удаленной БД через phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, localhost

Помогите пожалуйста! Не получается подключиться к удаленной БД через PhpMyAdmin: как указано в инструкции http://sforsuresh.in/access-remote-mysql-server-using-local-phpmyadmin/ в файле config.inc.php я добавила следующие строчки (остальное оставила без изменений):

```
$i++; 
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '172.12.6.1:5333';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'postg';   //Имя пользователя
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123';  //Пароль
```

Перезапустила Denwer, но страница PhpmyAdmin пустая, даже никакой ошибки не написано.
В чём может быть проблема?
Если это важно, в файле config.inc.php еще были строчки

`/* User used to manipulate with storage */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';`

Я их оставила без изменений.

Comment: В логах веб сервера на которой phpmyadmin крутится есть че?

Comment: В логах (\usr\local\apache\logs)  следующее: 
error.log   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mqfezb8YUDR0RJU0ZxUV85U3c/view?usp=sharing

access.log https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mqfezb8YUDd1BjS3F2RmxjN3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: В логах ничего интересного, они на момент коннекта к удаленной БД? А удаленная БД разрешает коннекты из вне(кроме 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что БД там не MySQL, а PostgreSQL.

Comment: Бывает =) 12345